# Adding Hidden Attribute To Select Option Based On Option Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a working function that will hide specific select options based on certain values. The options will not have a class or id so I need to use the option value as an identifier.

Does anyone see a problem with this function?

```
function delivery_rate(valMap) {
    if(valMap === 5000){
        $(".addon-select option[value="1-day-1"]").setAttribute("hidden", true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I see is that `hidden` is not a valid attribute for [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) elements, or property for the [`HTMLOptionElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement). But did you try it, did it work?

Comment: @DavidThomas Hi, it does not work. I thought hidden was a valid html5 attribute. This line breaks the rest of my script - `$(".addon-select option[value="1-day-1"]").setAttribute("hidden", true);`

Comment: Because you've got `"` within the string you've delimited with `"` characters, either escape the `"` characters inside the string (`\"`) or use `'` characters to wrap the string. Also `setAttribute()` is standard JavaScript, and not a valid jQuery method for the jQuery object you've selected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying hidden on the options tag, create different versions of `<select>` and set all to be hidden. When a user selects a value that matches the criteria of that `<select>` tag, show that specific tag.

```
<select name="select" class="first-select">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>

<select name="select" class="second-select">
  <option value="value4">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value5" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value6">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but the select input is created dynamically by a woocommerce plugin, which is why I need to be able to target specific options.

Comment: Can you modify the plugin to show only the options you want using PHP rather than hiding the elements using CSS/JS?

Comment: It's only for one out of 50 different products. So I'm trying not to cause any problems down the line with that plugin by editing the source.